# Mvel's compiled expression how to store in database

Tags: java, database, serializable, mvel

I have to save the compiled expression from MVel in database.
So that I can use this directly to evaluate the expression.
How can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All compiled expressions are serializable, and thus can be saved as blobs.

Comment: Yes, I could able to save the compiled expression as blob and retrieve the same, could use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it make more sense to store it in its external source form? Parsing and construction is unlikely to be much overhead, if you already have to do database access which is much much slower.

Storing source is readable, and it may well be more compact -- binary serialization format may or may not be compact. Default JDK serialization, for example, is very verbose since it includes lots of Java class metadata.

So are you sure there is actual benefit from storing binary representations.

Comment: Storing the compiled expression makes it one step less just before using Mvel with the expression. As the same expressions are used again and again it makes much faster to when using compiled expressions.

Comment: Have you actually MEASURED effects? This just sounds like a case of pre-mature optimization -- I am not saying compilation does not take time, but that's not the question; rather it is, is that enough to matter? Same goes for size: make sure to validate your assumptions; otherwise you are just guessing. Binary representation is more fragile; more likely to break with new MVEL version and so on.